# Why do I get random errors while executing jest tests that call cognito lambda triggers PostConfirmation and then PreTokenGeneration?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have one `PostConfirmation` lambda trigger that adds data to **DynamoDB**  via **GraphQL** (appsync https call) and then I query for that info in the `PreTokenGeneration` lambda.
When I test manually via my app UI things work.
But when executing via Jest tests, 50%+ of the time I get an error due to the supposed record info not being found in DynamoDB.
The problem doesn't occur when I test manually via UI app. Only when executing via Jest test.

I checked the Cloudwatch timestamps for the `PostConfirmation` DynamoDB record addition, `PreTokenGeneration` and checked the createDate in DynamoDB. The timestamps look ok.
For instance:

- The `PostConfirmation` log entry that says the record was added has the timestamp at `2020-08-24T17:51:06.463Z`.
- The **DynamoDB** `createdAt` for the added record (createdAt) says the record was created at `2020-08-24T17:51:06.377Z`.
- The `PostConfirmation` lambda "END RequestId: xxxxx"  has the timestamp at `2020-08-24T17:51:06.465-05:00`
- The PreTokenGeneration lambda starts at `2020-08-24T17:51:12.866Z` and at `2020-08-24T17:51:13.680Z` the query result says it didn't find any record.

Can someone help me or give me a hint about why this happen and/or how can I troubleshoot this problem? Thank you in advance.

Taking into account the answers from @noel-llevares I modified the VTL template to include the ConsistentRead=true but the problem remains.

Heres is the RequestMapping logged for the save operation

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "createAccountMember"
    ],
    "fieldName": "createAccountMember",
    "resolverArn": "arn:aws:appsync:xx-xxxx-x:111111111:apis/<redacted>/types/Mutation/resolvers/createAccountMember",
    "requestId": "<redacted>",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "input": {
                "id": "<redacted>",
                "userID": "<redacted>",
                "accountID": "<redacted>",
                "membershipStatus": "active",
                "groupsEnrolledIn": [
                    <redacted>
                ],
                "recordOwner": "<redacted>",
                "createdAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z",
                "__typename": "AccountMember"
            }
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Mutation",
    "graphQLAPIId": "<redacted>",
    "transformedTemplate": "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{\n  \"version\": \"2018-05-29\",\n  \"operation\": \"PutItem\",\n  \"key\":  {\n  \"id\":   {\"S\":\"<redacted>\"}\n} ,\n  \"attributeValues\": {\"accountID\":{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},\"createdAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z\"},\"recordOwner\":{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},\"__typename\":{\"S\":\"AccountMember\"},\"id\":{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},\"membershipStatus\":{\"S\":\"active\"},\"userID\":{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},\"groupsEnrolledIn\":{\"L\":[{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"},{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"}]},\"updatedAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z\"}},\n  \"condition\": {\"expression\":\"attribute_not_exists(#id)\",\"expressionNames\":{\"#id\":\"id\"}}\n}\n"
}
```

The ResponseMapping logged for the save operation

```
{
    "logType": "ResponseMapping",
    "path": [
        "createAccountMember"
    ],
    "fieldName": "createAccountMember",
    "resolverArn": "<redacted>",
    "requestId": "<redacted>",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "input": {
                "id": "<redacted>",
                "userID": "<redacted>",
                "accountID": "<redacted>",
                "membershipStatus": "active",
                "groupsEnrolledIn": [
                    "<redacted>",
                    "<redacted>",
                    "<redacted>"
                ],
                "recordOwner": "<redacted>",
                "createdAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z",
                "updatedAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z",
                "__typename": "AccountMember"
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "accountID": "<redacted>",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z",
            "recordOwner": "<redacted>",
            "__typename": "AccountMember",
            "id": "<redacted>",
            "membershipStatus": "active",
            "userID": "<redacted>",
            "groupsEnrolledIn": [
                "<redacted>",
                "<redacted>",
                "<redacted>"
            ],
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z"
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Mutation",
    "graphQLAPIId": "<redacted>",
    "transformedTemplate": "{\"accountID\":\"<redacted>\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z\",\"recordOwner\":\"<redacted>\",\"__typename\":\"AccountMember\",\"id\":\"<redacted>\",\"membershipStatus\":\"active\",\"userID\":\"<redacted>\",\"groupsEnrolledIn\":[\"<redacted>\",\"<redacted>\",\"<redacted>\"],\"updatedAt\":\"2020-08-25T05:11:10.917Z\"}\n"
}
```

Here's is the Request mapping logged for the list operation. You can see the `consistentRead=true`

```
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "listAccountMembers"
    ],
    "fieldName": "listAccountMembers",
    "resolverArn": "<redacted>",
    "requestId": "<redacted>",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "filter": {
                "userID": {
                    "eq": "<redacted>"
                }
            }
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Query",
    "graphQLAPIId": "<redacted>,
    "transformedTemplate": "  \n{\"version\":\"2018-05-29\",\"limit\":100,\"consistentRead\":true,\"filter\":{\"expression\":\"(#userID = :userID_eq)\",\"expressionNames\":{\"#userID\":\"userID\"},\"expressionValues\":{\":userID_eq\":{\"S\":\"<redacted>\"}}},\"operation\":\"Scan\"}"
}
```

Here is the responseMapping logged.  You can see the result is an empty array (`items:[]`) even though the record has been added previously and we have specified `consistentRead=true` for the query.

```
{
    "logType": "ResponseMapping",
    "path": [
        "listAccountMembers"
    ],
    "fieldName": "listAccountMembers",
    "resolverArn": "<redacted>",
    "requestId": "<redacted>",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "filter": {
                "userID": {
                    "eq": "<redacted>"
                }
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "items": [],
            "nextToken": "<redacted>",
            "scannedCount": 100
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": false,
    "errors": [],
    "parentType": "Query",
    "graphQLAPIId": "<redacted>",
    "transformedTemplate": "\n{\"items\":[],\"nextToken\":\"<redacted>",\"scannedCount\":100,\"startedAt\":null}\n"
}
```

What else could I be missing?

**UPDATE02**

I found the possible cause. It's beacause I'm new to how DynamoDB works. The query or scan operations get the results by key. In this case there is no key involved, so it gets all the records taking the limit into account. In my case it's 100, and then it applies the filter. So if the record added is not in the first 100 results it can't find it unless I go through the paging (not good for muy specific need).

**TL;DR**: I changed the query to use a @key directive with userID as the key field and the problem has gone because que field is a GSI and the number of records I expect to retrieve with such partition is much less than the 100 limit. I'll add this as part of the answer as soon as I finish undoing the tweaks i previously made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. The query or scan operations get the results by key. In this case there is no key involved, so it gets all the records taking the limit into account, in my case it's 100, and then it applies the filter. So if the record added is not in the first 100 results it can't find it unless I go through paging (not good for my specific need). I didn't notice this because I'm new to how DynamoDB works. But thank to @noel-llevares I went through more in-depth research to find a solution.

The solution was to change the query to use a `@key` directive with name "byUsername" that exists in the `AccountMember` type with `userID` as the key field and the problem has gone because que field is a GSI and the number of records I expect to retrieve with such partition is much less than the 100 limit.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is *eventually consistent* by default.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html),

> When you read data from a DynamoDB table, the response might not reflect the results of a recently completed write operation. The response might include some stale data. If you repeat your read request after a short time, the response should return the latest data.

If you need to read what you just wrote immediately, you can opt to use strongly consistent reads. This is usually done by specifying `ConsistentRead` to `true` in your DynamoDB calls.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I modified the VTL template to add `ConsistenRead` for the query that retrieves a list of records of the type that gets saved but it still fails randomly. I Checked the log to make sure the config is correctly set. I will update my question quit the RequestMappings for saving and for que query. I hope you can help me to know what else I'm missing. Thank you.

Comment: Why do your Lambda triggers use DynamoDB via GraphQL when you can just use DynamoDB directly?

Comment: Because I'm new to Amplify & AWS stuff so I don't now much about how to interact with DynamoDB directly. I come from MongoDB and SQL field for persistence but DynamoDB is the straightforward way to work with amplify taking advantage of its directives and so on.

Comment: It may or may not solve your issue but using DynamoDB directly will give you a quicker runtime, cheaper cost, and easier development and debugging experience.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for the help. At this moment I found the root cause of my problem and updated my question. I'll add it as an answer later. I'll definitively take your advice into account for a near future optimization for the lambda triggers.